# Counting the number of occurrences of the word [error] and [notice] in a log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, wc

I am facing a small problem over here in Linux Ubuntu trying to count the number of occurrences of the words [error] and [notice] in a log file that I have over here. Here is what I have tried so far :

```
grep -o -i '[error]' apache.log | wc -l
```

Using grep and these options to count as if lines don't matter, and :

```
grep -o -i '[notice]' apache.log | wc -l
```

However, I don't arrive to the given answer, and I am not sure what is wrong with my command line, if someone could give me an input on all of this.

Thanks!

Comment: apache.log is the name of my log file.

Comment: Do you know what `[]` means in regular expressions?

Comment: Use `grep -F` if you're looking for a fixed string rather than a regular expression. And use the `-c` option instead of piping to `wc -l`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `-o` when you're just piping the output to `wc` and `-i` wouldn't be necessary either given your description.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```sh
grep -oi '\[notice]' apache.log | wc -l
```

*Details*:

- `-o` - output matched texts only
- `-i` - case insensitive matching
- `\[notice]` - a literal `[notice]` string (since the pattern is parsed as a POSIX BRE pattern, you need to escape `[`).

Or, to match a fixed string pattern:

```sh
grep -oiF '[notice]' apache.log | wc -l
```

where `-F` will force `grep` to search for a fixed `[notice]` string.

Comment: Good answer to the question that was asked but chances are all the OP really needs is `grep -cF '[notice]' apache.log`

Comment: @EdMorton That was my initial thought, but that would be an answer to a different question.